# How to get Last and Secondlast Record from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

[image]

From the above image i have **n** number of records with **cat_id** and  **sub_cat_id** but in image only two are there.

so i want get the **last** and **secondlast** `score_in_per` value as named `lastScore` and `latetsScore`..

how can i retrieve that..?

```
SELECT
(SELECT score_in_per FROM tbl_student_skill_score ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2,0)  as lastScore,
(SELECT score_in_per FROM tbl_student_skill_score ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)  as latetsScore
```

i am new to this complicated mysql logics..This what i have tried..

**Example:**
lets say one user email is `inststudent@yopmail.com`  take the same test `2` times and the test is linked up with one category and sub category. 
so the user will take the test any number of times...

> from that records i want to get the last two records percentage.

Comment: And what is the issue with your subquery?  What results do you want?  I don't see how the circled rows would be the latest or second latest.

Comment: its not working, sometimes it said inner query is getting multiple values.. and now latetsScore coming but last score coming as `null`

Comment: let me explain a bit clearly in question give one minute.

Comment: Percentage of what? What is desired output from your table ?

Comment: Can you use a tool like http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables. Create a table then give us the output you want.

Comment: not percentage of anything.... there is a column in image `score_in_per` i just want to retrive that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  
(   SELECT score_in_per     FROM   tbl_student_skill_score WHERE cat_id=1 and sub_cat_id=5 ORDER BY date,id DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS latestScore,
(   SELECT score_in_per     FROM   tbl_student_skill_score WHERE cat_id=1 and sub_cat_id=5 ORDER BY date,id DESC LIMIT 1,1  ) AS lastScore
```

Answer (score 1):

**If I understand you correctly; you want to select the two most recent results of a specific type of test taken by a specific student.**

You don't use the `LIMIT` clause correctly. This is the correct syntax: `LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}`. Also, you completely left out the where clause.

So the query should be:

```
SELECT
(SELECT score_in_per FROM tbl_student_skill_score
  WHERE user_email = "email of the user you are interested in"
    AND cat_id = categoryOfTestOfInterest
    AND sub_cat_id = subcategoryOfTestOfInterest
  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1, 1
)AS lastScore,
(SELECT score_in_per FROM tbl_student_skill_score
  WHERE user_email = "email of the user you are interested in"
    AND cat_id = categoryOfTestOfInterest
    AND sub_cat_id = subcategoryOfTestOfInterest
  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
)AS latetsScore;
```

If a student can take the test multiple times a day (like your image suggests) than you should also order by id (supposing that the id is always greater for newer results) or better still, only by the id:

```
SELECT
(SELECT score_in_per FROM tbl_student_skill_score
  WHERE user_email = "email of the user you are interested in"
    AND cat_id = categoryOfTestOfInterest
    AND sub_cat_id = subcategoryOfTestOfInterest
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 1
)AS lastScore,
(SELECT score_in_per FROM tbl_student_skill_score
  WHERE user_email = "email of the user you are interested in"
    AND cat_id = categoryOfTestOfInterest
    AND sub_cat_id = subcategoryOfTestOfInterest
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
)AS latetsScore;
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the way of solving this problem is by using **Partition By**  .
**Step1:** I have ranked the data for distinct cat_id and sub_cat_id in descending order of date by partition by.
**Step2:** I have used rank1 which is the latest score and merged it with rank2 which is the second last score

```
with chck as
(select
   cat_id,sub_cat_id,score_in_per,date1,
   row_number() over(partition by cat_id,sub_cat_id order by 
   cat_id,sub_cat_id,date1 desc) as row_num
from tbl)

    select a.*,b.second_last_score from
    (select cat_id,sub_cat_id,score_in_per,date1,row_num as last_score from chck where row_num=1) a
    left join
    (select cat_id,sub_cat_id,score_in_per,date1,row_num as second_last_score from chck where row_num=2) b
    on a.cat_id = b.cat_id and a.sub_cat_id = b.sub_cat_id;
```

Let me know in case of any query.